# Kendo UI Treeview - update checkbox state when bound to local data

Tags: javascript, checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a JavaScript object with **items** array to define hierarchy. When I create a **kendoTreeView** widget with this data, **loadOnDemand** set as false, the checkboxes that should have been indeterminate, show up as unchecked.

What I did to fix this was to set **loadOnDemand** as true, expand all nodes and collapse them.

The expanding and collapsing is necessary as I am working on the leaf nodes of the tree on user interaction.

Is there a way to achieve this with **loadOnDemand** set as false?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/local-data-binding">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example">

      <div class="demo-section k-content">
        <h4>Inline data (default settings)</h4>
        <div id="treeview-left"></div>
      </div>


      <script>
        var inlineDefault = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({                      
          data: [{

            "Name": "Test",
            "enabled": true,
            "text": "Test",
            "id": "Test",
            "Description": null,
            "Key": null,
            "items": [{
              "Name": "Workspace",
              "enabled": true,
              "text": "Workspace",
              "id": "Workspace",
              "Description": null,
              "Key": null,
              "items": [],
              "checked": true,
              "expanded": true
            },
                      {
                        "Name": "Deploy",
                        "enabled": true,
                        "text": "Deploy",
                        "id": "Deploy",
                        "Description": null,
                        "Key": null,
                        "items": [{
                          "Name": "Test.Deploy.Application",
                          "enabled": true,
                          "text": "Application",
                          "id": "Test.Deploy.Application",
                          "Description": "",
                          "Key": "Test.Deploy.Application",
                          "items": [],
                          "checked": false,
                          "expanded": true
                        },
                                  {
                                    "Name": "Test.Deploy.Visualization",
                                    "enabled": true,
                                    "text": "Visualization",
                                    "id": "Test.Deploy.Visualization",
                                    "Description": "",
                                    "Key": "Test.Deploy.Visualization",
                                    "items": [],
                                    "checked": true,
                                    "expanded": true
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "Name": "Test.Deploy.Application Workspace",
                                    "enabled": true,
                                    "text": "Application Workspace",
                                    "id": "Test.Deploy.Application Workspace",
                                    "Description": "",
                                    "Key": "Test.Deploy.Application Workspace",
                                    "items": [],
                                    "checked": false,
                                    "expanded": true
                                  }],
                        "checked": null,
                        "expanded": true
                      }],
            "checked": null,
            "expanded": true
          }]

        });

        $("#treeview-left").kendoTreeView({
          dataSource: inlineDefault,
          checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: true,
          },
          loanOnDemant:false,
        });


      </script>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Its work for me!! 
[For more details](http://www.telerik.com/forums/bind-checkboxes-to-datasource-field-in-the-treeview)